# Understanding sucess(job,duration)

Tags: jobs, autosys

I have a query regarding lookback condition. Say for example I have a job B with this condition:

```
s(jobA,01.30)
```

Does the condition mean that the job B will execute every 1.5 hrs if the job A is in success state? Or only be triggered once after 1.5 hrs when the job A is successful?